# Do I still have to alloc my object if I'm using a property

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, properties

Simple question I can't seem to find a fast post for;

if I have an object, lets say:

```
 NSString *myString_;
 @property(readwrite, retain)NSString* myString;
 @synthesize myString = myString_;
```

When I synthesize this, does this alloc memory for the object?

Thanks

Comment: sorry about all the edits. could't get the code to post correctly

Comment: This is a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488446/is-a-synthesized-property-already-alloc-init-ed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that @synthesize does is generate the accessors (setter and getter) for your property and create an instance variable with the same name. The added step of using the equals sign:

```
@synthesize mystring = _string;
```

... renames the instance variable for you to _string (or whatever name you choose, the underbar is just an apple convention). This is good practice since having the instance variable share the same name as the accessors can be problematic. Having the underbar lets you differentiate between the two.

This is basically what is generated (assume ARC is ON):

```
// getter
- (NSString*)mystring
{
    return _string;
}
```

and

```
// setter
- (void)setMyString:(NString*)myString
{
    _myString = myString;
}
```

You can initialize you property in an init method (using self.propertyName):

```
-(id)init
{
    self.myString = @"Something"; // or use an alloc init method in the class   
}
```

or you can initialize it lazily by overriding the getter like so:

```
- (NSString*)myString
{
    if (!_myString) {  // same as saying if nil and therefore doesn't exist yet
        _myString = @"Something";
    }
    return _myString;
}
```

Also note you don't need to declare your variable separately (i.e. you don't need NSString* mystring). Just use strong or weak in place of retain when declaring the property.

The only places you should access the instance variable directly is in the accessors, this allows you to control all action to it through a single gateway. The overhead of using the accessors within the class (i.e self.mystring) is infinitesimal. Of course you don't have to do it this way, but it's good practice.

Answer (score 2):

No.  You'll either alloc & init an object and then set the property to it, ala:

```
self.myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: @"Hello Miek"];
```

or you'll have an already allocated & retained string which you'll set your new property to.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: No, the property and synthesize call won't allocate any memory. You have to do it. If you don't, the myString actually points to nil upon construction.
Don't use Michael's example though, as it leaks memory.

Use

```
self.myString = @"Hello Miek";
```

The @ literal is actually equivalent to calling [NSString stringWithString:] class method
which returns an autoreleased (and of course allocated) object. Alternatively you could use this

```
NSString *aString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: @"string...."];
self.myString = aString;
[aString release];
```

Also note, you should declare the property as copy instead of retain for NSStrings.
In your dealloc, you have to release myString too.

And finally, Patrick's answer isn't 100% correct, since the synthesised setter for the retained property looks like this:

```
-(void) setMyString: (NSString*) string {
    [myString release];
    myString = [string retain];
 }
```

And on a final note related to Patrick's answer, it is not recommended to use setters in
the init method. So rather than

```
self.myString = @"xyz";
```

It is recommended to access the iVar directly:

```
//or _myString, if you synthesized it that way of course
myString = @"xyz";
[myString retain];
```

Cheers (long answer, had a little time on my hand ;)

Comment: props for posting the memory managed accessor implementations; my answer assumes the user is on iOS5 with ARC enabled, calls to release or retain will fail with ARC on. Also read my update above regarding accessing the iVars directly outside accessors.