# Synthesized Property Unretained

Tags: objective-c

I've just figured out why some code has just failed to work. I've got something like the following:

```
@interface Client : NSObject {
    Connection *connection;
}

@property (retain) NSMutableDictionary *channels;
```

Followed by this implementation:

```
@implementation Client

@synthesize channels;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
         // do whatever I want
         NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Any idea why `channels` has a memory address of 0x0 in the `init` constructor for this class? I can't figure out for the life of me why this is happening. I'm definitely calling that constructor, and it should be synthesizing the property allowing me to do whatever I want with it.

Comment: None of the code you've shown initialized `channels`, so I'd expect it's value to be `0`.  Have you left out something important?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488446/is-a-synthesized-property-already-alloc-init-ed?rq=1

Comment: `@synthesize` doesn't automatically `alloc` an object for you. It just creates a getter and setter for that variable.

Comment: @CarlNorum I just pooped myself the moment I saw your comment. I am a tired man indeed. Whack that as your answer so I can mark it as correct instead of a comment.

Comment: Don't sweat it, there are a couple of answers that say the same thing already.  You can just pick one of those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you explicitly set `channels` to a value, it will remain `nil`. Perhaps you meant to do the following in your `init` method?

```
if (self) {
     // do whatever I want
     channels = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}
```

Two more ways to set channels:

```
[self setChannels:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]]; //These two lines...
self.channels = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];    //...are equivalent.
```

Note that in that case, because we are using your `retain` accessors, we use the autoreleased `+dictionary` rather than `alloc`/`init`, which would leak if not using ARC.

Of course, `channels` must also be properly released in `-dealloc`, if not using ARC:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [channels release];
}
```

Comment: This is correct. I am now embarrassed by the stupidity. It's a cut-down version of a crap load of code. How I missed it I don't know.

Comment: These things happen; perhaps this question will be useful to someone in the future that thinks properties come automatically filled with objects.

Comment: @andyvn22, alloc/init would only leak when not using ARC if you also forget to release in dealloc.  All of your example above should have `[channels release];` in dealloc when not using ARC (even for the retained property).

Comment: @AW101, alloc/init would *not* leak if directly assigned to the ivar, as in the first example (assuming proper release in `-dealloc`). It *would* leak in the second example, even if properly released in `-dealloc`, because the accessor will retain the new value.

Comment: @andyvn22, correct. I think I'm just pointing out that in all your examples you need to release in dealloc.

Comment: Sure, I suppose those that need to see this question might also need a reminder about `dealloc`. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

It is 0x0 because you are never setting channels to anything. You at least need to do:

```
channels = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

and then in dealloc you must remember to:

```
[channels release];
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, not using the synthesized setter method, you need to manually invoke `retain` on the alloc'd variable here don't you?

Comment: No, `alloc` will increment the retain count so `retain` isn't required.  If I also called `retain` I would have to call `release` twice. Remember: new, alloc, retain and copy all increment the retain count, so will need releasing.